# OpenLayers 3 Cesium - NaN coordinates

Tags: openlayers, cesium

I had a `openlayers 3` map with `EPSG:4258` as view's projection and some layers into it.
Now I would like to use `Cesium` and be able to switch 2D/3D map.
I follow the steps from his repository https://github.com/openlayers/ol3-cesium
but I have some problems.
Here's my maps init.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attribution: false // No atribución
  }).extend([mousePositionControl, // MousePosition
    //new ol.control.FullScreen(), // FullScreen
    new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({tipLabel: 'Leyenda'}), // LayerSwitcher
    new ol.control.ScaleLine(), // ScaleLine
    //new ol.control.ZoomSlider(), // ZoomSlider
  ]),
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: proj,
    zoom: 3,
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-0.47343, 39.42811], 'EPSG:4258'),
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 10

  })
}),
ol3d = new olcs.OLCesium({
  map : map
}),
scene = ol3d.getCesiumScene(),
terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
  url : '//assets.agi.com/stk-terrain/world'
});

ol3d.setEnabled(true);
```

Nothing is rendered if I enable the Cesium map.
MousePositionControl show NaN coordinates.

Also I get an error if I try to add Layers to map after `ol3d.setEnable(true)` is set.

[image]